# How to install & activate a c-lightning plugin in lightningd?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, plugins

I recently stumbled across the https://github.com/lightningd/plugins github repo and wanted to install the autopilot plugin. But how can I install and activate the plugin which I downloaded from the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained on the [simple funds overview plugin](https://github.com/renepickhardt/c-lightning-plugin-collection/tree/master/simpleFundsOverview) you just have to start `lightningd` with the `plugin` argument like this:

```
lightningd --plugin=/path/to/plugin/directory/plugin-file-name.py
```

of course plugins could also be written in other languages than python.

You see this mechanism also in action in [this video which explains who to write and run your own plugins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYs1I-pCJIg).

Also you can move the plugin to the `clightning` [codebase to the plugindirectory](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/tree/bc5dbb6a80f89210a25f98135db452ada5f14743/plugins) (version at time of giving that answer). plugins which are stored there are automatically called and activated on `lightningd` startup if the file of the plugin is executable.

You will also need c-lightning version bigger than 0.6 as plugins where not a thing before.